# Using eclipse and maven 2, how to get dependancy for sqljdbc4?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I am using eclipse with the maven 2 plugin.

I want to add the dependency for sqljdbc4, how can I do that?

Can't seem to find it via the 'add dependency' option in eclipse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If **sqljdbc4** is the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver, then you will very likely [**not  find it**](http://mavensearch.net/search?q=sqljdbc4) in any "public" repository because of licensing issues.

So you'll have to download it, unpack it and install it manually with either [`mvn install:install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) (or `mvn deploy:deploy-file` if you have a repository manager).

Another option would be to use [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) (which is open source and available in maven central repository) if your database engine is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your SQL server jar is sqljar-1.4.2.jar

Use the follwing command in maven cmd

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.org.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljar -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile="C:\sqljar-1.4.2.jar"
```

will install the sqljar in your local maven repository .

and then include follwing dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.org.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljar</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

your can change the group id or artifact id or version depending on your wish

Answer (score 0):

Use the maven-eclipse-plugin to generate your .classpath and .project and all will be well.

Failing that, you have to find the jar in your ~/.m2/repository and add it as an external library.