# Java + include sqljdbc4.jar for continuous integration server

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sqljdbc

does anyone know how I can use the sqljdbc4 jar file inside a project but without setting it in the build path of the project inside Eclpise?
I store my project in a source control repository and have a Countinuous Integration Server (Jenkins) to run my java tests.
If the sqljdbc4 jar is included at Eclipse level only, the Countinuous Integration Server yells it cannot find the class specified (using Class.forName()) as the file is not "shipped" with my java code.

I also use Maven but it seems to not be provided by Maven repository as dependency.

Or any alternative I could use instead of sqljdbc4?

Thanks;

Answer (score 3):

You may find this [Using eclipse and maven 2, how to get dependancy for sqljdbc4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2444669/569659) helpful as it shows you how to add sqljdbc4 as a dependency. You will have to do this on your CI server as well, unless you have a repository manager such as http://nexus.sonatype.org/, then you can install it there.

Comment: Thank you Tnemas I don't control the CIS nor much over the network and there is no nexus here, I switched to jtds instead of sqljdbc4, which works fine and is a dependency in Maven.

Comment: Think hard about using Nexus or any other Repository Manager if you are working with Maven.

Comment: @khmarbaise can you elaborate on why ?

Comment: It makes releasing artifacts within the company simpler and gives other people in your company the possibility to use those artifacts for their builds and your builds will be usually faster than with internet connection. Furthermore you can install artifacts which are not available via Maven central within your internal repository.

Comment: @khmarbaise I thought you meant think hard about using it, not think hard about not using it. Got it the wrong way round, glad we agree that Repository Management is awesome!